# is it possible to set custom metadata on files, using Java?

Tags: java, file

Is it possible to get and set custom metadata on File instances? I want to use the files that I process through my system as some kind of a very simple database, where every file should contain additional custom metadata, such as the email of the sender, some timestamps, etc.

It is for an internal system, so security is not an issue.

Comment: For a similar requirement I created an additional meta data file for every file, i.e. a file named `report.pdf` had a `report.pdf.meta` file which contained the meta data. Not as fancy as using extended attributes, but it worked.

Answer (score 8):

In java 7 you can do this using the [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) class and `UserDefinedFileAttributeView`.

Here is the example taken from there:

A file's MIME type can be stored as a user-defined attribute by using this code snippet:

```
Path file = ...;
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files
    .getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
view.write("user.mimetype",
           Charset.defaultCharset().encode("text/html");
```

To read the MIME type attribute, you would use this code snippet:

```
Path file = ...;
UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files
.getFileAttributeView(file,UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
String name = "user.mimetype";
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(view.size(name));
view.read(name, buf);
buf.flip();
String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf).toString();
```

Comment: What happens if you use `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` with a file system that doesn't natively support POSIX extended attributes, i.e. FAT? Is it emulated somehow?

Comment: I couldn't find a comprehensive list, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319586/what-file-sytems-support-java-userdefinedfileattributeview) answer lists a few file systems. I guess the only way to find out is it try it on FAT and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should always check if the filesystem supports `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` for the specific file you want to set
You can simply invoke this

```
Files.getFileStore(Paths.get(path_to_file))).supportsFileAttributeView(UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
```

From my experience, the `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` is not supported in FAT* and HFS+ (for MAC) filesystems