# Create Image file with specified properties in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I want to create a image file in Android with specified Author name and other properties like,

- Authors:
- Title:
- Subject:
- Program name:
- Copyright:
- etc...

I created Image file. How can I specify these properties?

Comment: You should create one `RelativeLayout` and put the image as background and then create textViews with custom styles and set all those at desired position in relative layout.

Comment: Apurva, Your comment is irrelavent to my question. I want to create a file having Authors,Title,etc. So I can verify that this file is created by me by checking its properties by right click on that file.

Comment: @close voter...pls specify the reason for closing.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906793/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-metadata-on-files-using-java I have no idea if it works on Android but it's worth a try. Or maybe try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955475/add-custom-attribute-or-metadata-to-file-java which seems to be simpler.

Comment: I tried it in java, but UserDefinedFileAttributeView is not available in Android.:(