# Java UserDefinedFileAttributeView

Tags: java, nio, xattr

When I add a new `UserDefinedFileAttributeView` attribute to a file, where does Java store this information? 
There are no additional files in the directory, the file does not have any new attributes or details when I view the file properties.

My code:

```
String versionAttrName = "report.version";
try {           
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath, "");
    UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
    view.write(versionAttrName, Charset.defaultCharset().encode(newVersion));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("7 - Error saving version to file! - "+ filePath + " - " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Did you check your user directories and `programdata` directories... I would recommend doing a hard drive search, will be the fastest way to find the file :)

Comment: Any thoughts on what to search for? Haha, I have no idea what file name/type Java would use

Answer (score 2):

These metadata are stored using file system's "extended file attributes" (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)).

I could not find any comprehensive list of file systems being supported (it is definitely JVM specific), so you should definitely test in on all platforms you plan to support. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319586/what-file-sytems-support-java-userdefinedfileattributeview) answer lists some and [this](http://web.ist.utl.pt/pedro.gloria/java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#user) mentions some details about Linux. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform you're running under.

As per the OpenJDK documentation: `The details of such emulation are highly implementation specific and therefore not specified.`

However testing on Windows indicates it uses NTFS Alternate Data Streams:

```
PS C:\test> Get-Item -Path C:\test\asdf.txt -stream *


   FileName: C:\test\asdf.txt

Stream                   Length
------                   ------
:$DATA                        0
myaltstream                1337
```

On linux it uses extended attributes.

Not sure about others - hope this helps :)